# How to convert an API Response into a file in JAVA

Tags: java, spring

i'm receiving a response from a API that looks like this:

> ```
> 10:46:13.460 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[text/plain,
> ```
>
> application/json, application/*+json, */*]
> 10:46:16.614 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 200 OK
> 10:46:16.615 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading to
> [java.lang.String] as "application/octet-stream"
> Response: ?PNG
>
> ```
> !2??t°?ú,EG0?ÉNY??'²ä??ò??L?ñUuW?ºª»?«{º{~?ù| q÷hÜS?]=?ÿNU?ÿ?[?O?   `?}¥?/   ¬+??÷?àñ¿û,¬7ëä¬-;?
>                                                                                                 ñ?LÄ-¬V?5?p:%d?a???!±²2b1??µ?
>     ?*  T   B?   ? PA   ?@   ?
>    ?*  T   B?   ? P A   ?@   ?
>     ?*  T   B?   ? PA   ?@   ?
>    ?*  T   B?   ? P A   ?@   ?
> ```

But when i'm trying to convert this into a file, the file is corrupted.
This is the code the i'm trying to use.

```
private static void saveFile(String filename, String path, byte[] octetStream) throws IOException {

    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path+filename)){
    System.out.println(octetStream.length);
    fos.write(octetStream);

     }
  
}
```

Does anyone know the name of this kind of data?
I've been doing some testing with local files and it looks like i'm receiving more bytes than the original file.
When a use PostMan, it returns the same response but when a save the response as a file, it downloads it correctly.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks
[Here's where i call the method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eBN9.png)

Comment: If the output is corrupted, doesn't this suggest that `octetStream` is itself corrupted?

Comment: I get that octet stream from a response.getBody().getBytes(), don't know if that's corrupting it.

Comment: `the file is corrupted.`, you mean you cannot view this file as a PNG image ?

Comment: Show the relevant code where you call `saveFile()`.

Comment: Sure, i'll edit my post